# Why doesn't Kaisei want to be seen by Yasaburou?

Tags: the-eccentric-family

Kaisei is Souun's daughter, she is Yasaburou's cousin and ex-fiancée. But why doesn't she want Yasaburou to see her?

[image: Kaisei from last episode]

Comment: She probably likes him and is very shy about it.

Comment: @Hakase are you the same hakase that posted [here?](http://www.blog5star.com/why-doesnt-kaisei-want-to-be-seen-by-yasaburou/)

Comment: @Mindwin I suppose that's one of the hundreds of sites that copypastes everything from stackexchange, so I guess

Comment: Possibly because she's ashamed that she's an Ebisugawa? [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Eccentric_Family#Ebisugawa_Family) seems to imply she already knew of her father's plans to get rid of Souichirō and unlike the rest of the Ebisugawa who seem to harass the Shimogamo she seems to be very friendly with them even looking after Mother Shimogamo during a storm and breaking Yashirō out of the warehouse yet her father gave a death sentence to her uncle (and given how much Mother Shimogamo liked her we might assume Souichirō was the same to her)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was finally revealed in the follow-up "The Eccentric Family 2."

The earlier series had established that some tanuki have stimuli that undo their transformations -- Yasaburo's mother, for example, loses her ability to hold on to her transformation when she sees or hears lightning, and she reverts to tanuki form.

The reason Kaisei hides herself from Yasaburo is that *she* is the stimulus that makes him lose control of his transformation.  If he sees her, he reverts to tanuki state.

It's never explained (at least, not in the anime) how Kaisei knows this, when Yasaburo doesn't.  However, it's implied that she's known this all along, and secretly regarded their engagement as ultimately impossible because of it.

Comment: i guess that means most Tanuki's stimulus is Benten considering what happened at the end of season 1

Comment: Kaisei knows this from an earlier experience, perhaps when they were both much younger. That's how I understood their exchange. In addition to being very shy in the company of each other it makes sense.